# JQuery Ajax neat way to send input arrays in the request?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, ajax

Looks like my main issue was using .val() when I should have been using map, thank you @Barmar!

Though I'm still looking for a way to achieve the second array structure at the bottom of my post. It seems like the HTML structure would have to be:

```html
<div>
   <input type="text" name="student[1][name]">
   <input type="number" name="student[1][score]">

   <input type="text" name="student[2][name]">
   <input type="number" name="student[2][score]">

   <input type="text" name="student[3][name]">
   <input type="number" name="student[3][score]">
</div>
```

The challenge with this is the ID number is dynamic, so I'm not sure how to fit this in a Jquery selector. Would I just be selecting by "student" i.e.

```js
let input_names = $('input[name^="student["]').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

---

I have a lot of inputs that are of the same kind so I want them in arrays, i.e.

```html
<div>
   <input type="text" name="name_[1]">
   <input type="number" name="score_[1]">

   <input type="text" name="name_[2]">
   <input type="number" name="score_[2]">

   <input type="text" name="name_[3]">
   <input type="number" name="score_[3]">
</div>
```

The number in-between the brackets is the ID grouping related elements together. I want to be able to send all the values in arrays in an AJAX request but can't seem to figure it out. Only the first elements get sent, not an array

```js
let input_names = $('input[name^="name_"]').val();
let input_scores = $('input[name^="score_"]').val();

$.ajax({
    url: "../util/funcs.php",
    async: true,
    data: {
        a: "backendFunction",
        input_names: input_names,
        input_scores: input_scores
    }
})
.done(function(data) {
    console.log("Success");
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("Error");
.always(function() {
    // alert( "complete" );
});
```

I want a way to neatly send them to the backend, either as separate arrays by name parameter or ideally grouped by ID. So the $_REQUEST would look something like:

```
[ids] =>
    [1, 2]
[names] =>
    ["alex", "john"]
[scores] =>
    [30, 70]
```

Or even better:

```
[1] =>
    [name]  => "alex"
    [score] => "30"
[2] =>
    [name]  => "john"
    [score] => "70"
```

Unfortunately either way I try, the AJAX only seems to send the first of each input, rather than arrays. Please help!

Comment: You have no names that begin with `name_` or `score_`. There are no underscores in the names.

Comment: Are the inputs in a form? If you use `$("#formid").serialize()` it will do the right thing.

Comment: @Barmar The inputs are not in a form, I will look into this though! As for the names being wrong, I was trying to quickly type a simpler example, sorry for the confusion. The names are the same in my document . Will fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.val()` only returns the value of the first element that matches the selector, not all of them. You need to loop over all the matches to get all the values.

```
let input_names = $('input[name^="name["]').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
let input_scores = $('input[name^="score["]').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Comment: this worked! Though, does JQuery work on a more complex selector such as `<input name="student[1][name]">` ? I don't know of a way to do this in Jquery selector because the ID will be dynamic, but it seems like this would achieve the second array structure I'm looking for

Comment: Yes, `.serialize()` will do the right thing with names like that. In PHP that would become `$_POST['student'][1]['name']`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution to get your desired object format:

```js
$(function() {
  let result = $('input').map(function() {
    return { name: this.name, value: this.value };
  }).get().reduce((acc, obj) => {
    let num = obj.name.replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');
    let key = obj.name.replace(/_.*$/, '');
    if(!acc[num]) {
      acc[num] = {};
    }
    acc[num][key] = obj.value;
    return acc;
  }, {});
  console.log('result:', result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <input type="text" name="name_[1]" value="Alex">
   <input type="number" name="score_[1]" value="101">
   <input type="text" name="name_[2]" value="Berta">
   <input type="number" name="score_[2]" value="102">
   <input type="text" name="name_[3]" value="Dora">
   <input type="number" name="score_[3]" value="103">
</div>
```

Output:

```
result: {
  "1": {
    "name": "Alex",
    "score": "101"
  },
  "2": {
    "name": "Berta",
    "score": "102"
  },
  "3": {
    "name": "Dora",
    "score": "103"
  }
}
```

Notes:

- first, get all input elements and build an array of `{ name, value }` objects
- then, use a `.reduce()` to accumulate the desired object format
- tweak the `.replace()` of `num` and `key` if you have different name input patterns

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" class="name_">
   <input type="number" class="score_">

   <input type="text"  class="name_">
   <input type="number"   class="score_">

   <input type="text"  class="name_">
   <input type="number"   class="score_">
   <input class="submit" type="button" value="submit"  />
<script>
$('.submit').click(function(){
    nam = $('.name_');
    scr = $('.score_');
    naml = nam.length;
    myar = new Array;
    i=0;
    for(i=0;i<naml;i+=1)
    {
    myar[i] = {'name':nam.eq(i).val(),'score':scr.eq(i).val()};
    }
    alert(JSON.stringify(myar));
});
</script>
```